# selected item of a spinner in an if statement

Tags: android, if-statement

How can I use `if statement` of a spinner when the selected value = 0?

```
if( wilayat.setSelection(0) || city.setSelection(0) ||
    station.setSelection(0) || distnation.setSelection(0)) {

            message = "Select the 4 fields, please..";
            Toast.makeText(BusArrivalTime.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: I think what you want is to check whether any spinner is empty and if empty then show this toast. is this you want?

Comment: Could you show the detail code?

Comment: It solved by @KeLiuyue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
if (wilayat.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 || city.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 || station.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 || distnation.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
        message = "Select the 4 fields, please..";
        Toast.makeText(BusArrivalTime.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Just use `getSelectedItemPosition()` method.

You make sure that `wilayat`、`city` and so on were Spinner.

Add judgement

```
if (wilayat != null || city != null || station != null || distnation != null) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you !